# Reactjs Slicing and keeping indexes

Tags: reactjs, slice

I get overlapping indexes 0,1 when slicing and mapping. How would I keep the same index while doing the same thing.I need to get the correct indices for <TextField value={paymentField[index]} onChange={(e)=>{setPaymentFields(e,index)}} variant="outlined" className={classes.paymentTextField}/> .

```
 <Grid container xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} className={classes.marginBottom}>
    {paymentRows.slice(0,3).map((row,index) =>
      <Grid key={index} item xs={12} className={classes.alignRow}>
      <Typography className={classes.accordionCheckMarkFor+" "+classes.paymentRowBlock} >
        {row}
      </Typography>
    
      {editable[1]?(
        <TextField value={paymentField[index]} onChange={(e)=>{setPaymentFields(e,index)}} variant="outlined" className={classes.paymentTextField}/>
        ):(
        <Typography  className={classes.accordionCheckMarkFor+" "+classes.paymentTextField} >
          {paymentField[index]}
        </Typography>
      )}
    
      </Grid>
    )}
</Grid>
<Grid container xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} className={classes.marginBottom} >
    {paymentRows.slice(3,5).map((row,index) =>
      <Grid key={index} item xs={12} className={classes.alignRow}>
      <Typography className={classes.accordionCheckMarkFor +" "+classes.paymentRowBlock} >
        {row}
      </Typography>
    
      {editable[1]?(
        <TextField value={paymentField[index]} onChange={(e)=>{setPaymentFields(e,index)}} variant="outlined" className={classes.paymentTextField}/>
        ):(
        <Typography className={classes.accordionCheckMarkFor+" "+classes.paymentTextField} >
          {paymentField[index]}
        </Typography>
      )}
    
      </Grid>
    )}
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain in clearer detail what "I get overlapping indices 0,1` means? Your code snippet is slicing from index 0 to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice` is returning a new array starting from `0` each time. Try filtering the items you want in each `map` as shown below:

```
<Grid container xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} className={classes.marginBottom}>
   {
      paymentRows.map((row, index) => {
         return index <3 ? (<Grid key={index} item xs={12} className={classes.alignRow}>/*JSX*/</Grid>)  : null
      })
    }
</Grid>
<Grid container xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6} className={classes.marginBottom} >
    {
      paymentRows.map((row, index) => {
         return index >=3 ? (<Grid key={index} item xs={12} className={classes.alignRow}>/*JSX*/</Grid>)  : null
      })
    }
</Grid>
```

Also if `paymentRow` has an id I suggest using it as `key` instead of index.